# "How to get the revers of string using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-3.7

I have taken the input from the user and then converted the string into the list object using the split method. Then reversed the list using reverse function and it is working well. But the problem is that I'm unable to get the last word from the string.

I'm have checked my loop and it's working fine.

```
s=input('enter any string:')
l=s.split()
l1=reversed(l)
for i in l1:
    l2=' '.join(l1)
    print(l2)
```

input:

```
learning python is very easy
```

output:

```
very is python learning
```

Answer (score 2):

`reversed` is a generator function that returns an iterator, so when you use a `for` statement to iterate over it, it consumes the first item (the last word in your case) for the first iteration, during which you consume the rest of the iterator with the `' '.join` method, which is why it returns only all but the last word in the string for the next `print` statement to output.

In other words, you don't need the `for` loop. The `' '.join` method alone will iterate through the iterator for you:

```
s=input('enter any string:')
l=s.split()
l1=reversed(l)
l2=' '.join(l1)
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reverse` method to reverse `l` in place.

```
l = s.split(" ").reverse()
return l[0]  #this would return the first word of reversed arr or last word of string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s=" ".join(input('enter any string:').split(' ')[::-1])
print(s)
```

This is a simple solution to your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for reversing the given string.

```
>>> a=input()
python is very easy
>>> s=' '.join(a.split()[::-1])
>>> s
'easy very is python'
```